# p5.js - path - problems loading canvas PDE to webserver

Tags: html, canvas, path, p5.js

I have a problem loading my canvas test123.pde into my webpage with pde made from p5.js.
The test123.pde is an example from the official p5.js page, which I'm using for testing cause it has definitely no errors in it. So I will not post the code.

[Here's an image of my php/html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYfyL.jpg)

The webpage is displaying a default canvas (in firefox it's an empty canvas with size 150*300) but not displaying my test123.pde :(

As you can see the link to the canvas is not underlined like the scriptEntry.js below.

So I'm assuming that the path is not right. But that's confusing me, because the folder **canvas** is on the same level like the folder **script**.

**/home/sites/site55/web/subs/kreativ**   -> that's the result from an **getcwd()** in PHP, which returns the path.

I unluckily tried: 
canvas data-processing-sources="/home/sites/site55/web/subs/kreativ/canvas/test123.pde"

canvas data-processing-sources="../canvas/test123.pde"

canvas data-processing-sources="../canvas/test123.pde"

canvas data-processing-sources="https://www.fazzke.net/subs/kreativ/canvas/test123.pde"

canvas data-processing-sources="https://kreative-kreaturen.fazzke.net/canvas/test123.pde"

[As you can see every other necessary files are loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s69ZH.jpg)

Thank you a lot for help (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out what the problem is. For everyone who's having the same issue:

In Processing you include your canvas with:

**canvas data-processing-sources="example.pde"**

In p5.js you include your canvas with

**script src="example.js"**